# How many circles with radius $x$ can one fit tangent to a circle with radius $y$?

Tags: geometry, circles

I tried to construct a circle with radius $x+y$ concentric to the central circle with radius $y$, reducing the question to finding the number of sides of a polygon with the circle of radius $x+y$ being the circumscribed circle, and side length $2x$. But then I realized that the $x$-circles would have to be tangent to their neighboring $x$-circles as well. From there I had essentially no idea how this could be solved.

Comment: Draw a picture.  It will then be obvious how you should proceed.

Comment: $\sin^{-1}\left(\frac x{x+y}\right)$ may be useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

\begin{align} 
\triangle O_0O_1T_0:\quad
\sin\tfrac{\pi}n&=\frac{R}{r+R}
,\\
n&=\frac{\pi}{\arcsin(\frac{R}{r+R})}
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

This figure should set you in the right direction:
[image]