# Arbitary number of circles tangent to each other and tangent to another circle in the center

Tags: geometry, circles

I have $n$ "outer" circles of equal size in an equilateral arrangement like in the pictures below, with each circle tangent to both of its nearest "outer" neighbors, and an "inner" circle that is tangent to each of the $n$ outer circles.

[image: Three big blue circles surrounding a smaller red one] [image: Five big blue circles surrounding a smaller red one]

Is there a general formula for the ratio of the radius of the outer circles to the radius of the inner circle, given a number *n* of outer circles I'd like to place in such an arrangement? How can I derive it?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4140578/409).

Comment: Thanks! That gets me what I wanted.